# Symfony4 Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem

Tags: symfony

I’m currently discovering symfony.I am trying to code some user account. There are two role : ADMIN_ROLE or USER_ROLE. When I try to connect an account, I have this message  « Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem. » even when I enter a wrong username/password !
I have been looking for a solution for days (in docs and on internet).

I can fill my database with my user thanks to the fixture (I can see it in SQLyog). I tried to erase ma database to create it again.

This is my security.yaml :

```
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: username
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: ~

        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login

        logout:
            path: app_logout

        # activate different ways to authenticate
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        # switch_user: true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY  }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

This is my UtilisateurFixtures (to create false data)

```
<?php
namespace App\DataFixtures;
use App\Entity\Utilisateur;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User;
//use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Tests\Fixtures\User;
class UtilisateurFixtures extends Fixture
{
/**
* @var UserPasswordEncoderInterface
*/
private $encoder;

public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
{
    $this->encoder = $encoder;
}

public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{

    $user = new Utilisateur();
    $user->setUsername('demo3');
    $user->setPassword($this->encoder->encodePassword($user,'demo3'));
    $user->setRoles(['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN']);
    $manager->persist($user);

    $manager->flush();
}
}
```

This is my SecurityController :

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
/**
* @Route("/login", name="login")
*/
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
{
// get the login error if there is one
$error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
// last username entered by the user
$lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function logout()
{
    // controller can be blank: it will never be executed!
    throw new \Exception('Don\'t forget to activate logout in security.yaml');
}
}
```

This is my Utilisateur.php :

```
<?php
namespace App\DataFixtures;
use App\Entity\Utilisateur;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User;
//use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Tests\Fixtures\User;
class UtilisateurFixtures extends Fixture
{
/**
* @var UserPasswordEncoderInterface
*/
private $encoder;

public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
{
    $this->encoder = $encoder;
}

public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{

    $user = new Utilisateur();
    $user->setUsername('demo3');
    $user->setPassword($this->encoder->encodePassword($user,'demo3'));
    $user->setRoles(['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN']);
    $manager->persist($user);

    $manager->flush();
}
}
```

This is my login.htlml.twig (where there is my form) :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Log in!{% endblock %}
{% block body %}{% if error %}
{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}
{% endif %}
<form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/" />

    {#
        If you want to control the URL the user
        is redirected to on success (more details below)
        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
    #}

    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is  UtilisateurRepository :

```
<?php
namespace App\Repository;
use App\Entity\Utilisateur;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;
/**
•   @method Utilisateur|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
•   @method Utilisateur|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
•   @method Utilisateur[] findAll()
•   @method Utilisateur[] findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
*/
class UtilisateurRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
{
parent::__construct($registry, Utilisateur::class);
}
// /**
// * @return Utilisateur[] Returns an array of Utilisateur objects
// /
/
public function findByExampleField($value)
{
return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
->andWhere('u.exampleField = :val')
->setParameter('val', $value)
->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC')
->setMaxResults(10)
->getQuery()
->getResult()
;
}
*/
/*
public function findOneBySomeField($value): ?Utilisateur
{
return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
->andWhere('u.exampleField = :val')
->setParameter('val', $value)
->getQuery()
->getOneOrNullResult()
;
}
*/
}
```

Thank you for your help ! Don't hesitate if you need anything.

Comment: your `routes.yaml` file please ?

Comment: A lot of things are missing here to make this working, I'll advise you to dig deeper into the symfony security component as there is no such thing as easy in it.

To help you a bit, you should configure your User provider to implements `UserProviderInterface` and the problem here is not about your data, but the component security itself that is obviously missconfigured

Where is your Guard (LoginAuthenticator) ?

Comment: If there is a "system problem" you probably can find a hint in your symfony's log (usually in `{symfonyProjectRoot}/var/log`).